# ajax jquery groups validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

here is my code:

```
groups: {
    phone: "phone1-phone2-phone3"
   digits: true
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "phone1" 
           || element.attr("name") == "phone2" || element.attr("name") == "phone3")
        error.insertAfter("#telephone");
    else
    error.insertAfter(element);
},
debug:true
```

here is my form input  text:

```
<p><label for="name"><span class="red">*</span>Phone: </label> <input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1" size="3" tabindex="12" />-<input type="text" name="phone2" id="phone2" size="3" tabindex="12" />-<input type="text" name="phone3" id="telephone" size="4" tabindex="12" /></p>
```

the above didnt validate? any ideas is much appreciated!

Comment: You should highlight your code within the edity box thing, and then click on the button with ones and zeros to format your code. I've done it for you already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the input ids in groups must be delimited by spaces not `-`. Here is the [code](http://jsbin.com/ejuca)

```
$("#form").validate({
groups: {
  phone: "phone1 phone2 telephone"
},
rules: {
  phone1 : "digits",
  telephone : "digits",
  phone2 : "digits"
},
onsubmit: false,
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "phone1"
           || element.attr("name") == "phone2" || element.attr("name") == "phone3")
        error.insertAfter("#telephone");
    else
    error.insertAfter(element);
},
debug:true
});
```

The rules need to be specified under the rules option

Comment: can i add another group to the list like this:
groups: {
      phone: "phone1 phone2 phone3",
      cell: "cell1 cell2 cell3"
    },
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         if (element.attr("name") == "phone1"
                || element.attr("name") == "phone2" || element.attr("name") == "phone3")
             error.insertAfter("#telephone");
         else if (element.attr("name") == "cell1"
                || element.attr("name") == "cell2" || element.attr("name") == "cell3")
             error.insertAfter("#cellu");
      else
         error.insertAfter(element);
     },

Comment: I don't know. will need to try it. Why don't you use the JSbin page I set up to test it?